# Dropping the parenthesis around the index items

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using python33, windows10 and the command line. I want to get rid of the parenthesis that appear around '7x3' and so on. Also, is there an easier way to do this? I ran into trouble with putting try and except statements under the while statements and the if else statements. Also I'm hoping there's a way to use the doMath() call as a parameter for bigMath(). And is there maybe a way to end an infinite loop in the shell without closing it? Is there anyone who could demonstrate this program using the lambda function keyword? All recommendations are welcome.

```
def doMath(Multiplication):
        b = [21, 32, 36, 42, 45, 48, 49, 54, 56, 63 ]
        n = [  '7 x 3' , ' 8 x 4 ', ' 9 x 4 ',' 7 x 6 ', ' 5 x 9 ',' 8 x 6 ' ,' 7 x 7 ', ' 9 x 6 ',' 7 x 8 ', ' 7 x 9 '  ]
        x = 0
        if Multiplication == b[x]:

            print('correct')


        else: 
            while Multiplication != b[x]:
                        print('Sorry that is an incorrect answer.')
                        try:
                                Multiplication=int(input ('Whats The Answer to (%s)? : ' % (n[x])))
                        except ValueError:
                                print('Numbers usally have no letters or special characters')
        while x <9:
                try:
                        Multiplication=int(input ('Whats The Answer to (%s)? : ' % (n[x+1])))   
                except ValueError:
                        print('Numbers usally have no letters or special characters')
                if Multiplication == b[x+1]:

                        print('correct')
                        x =  x+1

                elif x == 10:
                        break

                else: 

                        print('Sorry that is an incorrect answer.')

def bigMath():
        Multip = 'Pure Imagination'
        while Multip != 21:
                try:
                        Multip = int(input ('Whats The Answer to 7 x 3? '))
                        if Multip != 21:
                                print('Sorry that is an incorrect answer.')
                except ValueError:
                        print('Numbers usally have no letters or special characters')
        doMath(Multip)

bigMath()
```

Comment: do you mean `python 3.3`?

Comment: you can use [format](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#string-formatting) method of `str` class. Like, `'whats the answer to {}? :  '.format(n[x])` inside the `input()'

Comment: yes, sir-e 3.3, for accuracy and clarification.

Comment: did the above `format` method, solved your paranthesis problem?

Comment: Yes it did and it was quite free of errors and second attempts

Comment: Anything else, you'd like a help with?

Comment: do you know how I might import it into a GUI/tkinter program?